# Is there a way to create a command with choices in discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Is there a way to create a command using **discord.py**, that allows the user to select an option? I've painted an example as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BObKs.png) and the user shouldn't be able to type select / type other options than there are!

I've already tried doing it like this, but this unfortunately threw an error:

```py
@tree.command(name="createticket", description="Create a ticket", guild=discord.Object(GUILD_ID))
@app_commands.choices(choices=[
    app_commands.Choice(name="Bug", value="bug"),
    app_commands.Choice(name="Report", value="report")
    # ...
])
async def embed_command(interaction:discord.Interaction, choice:app_commands.Choice[str]):
    if interaction.user.guild_permissions.administrator and interaction.user != None:
        if choice.value == "bug":
           #open ticket code here
        elif choice.calue == "report":
           # ...
```

Error:

```py
TypeError: unknown parameter given: choices
```

*(Whole error shown [here](https://pastebin.com/PSpLqy28))*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you actually just made a typo: the parameter in `app_commands.choices` needs to have the same name as in your function.
So just replace by

```py
@app_commands.choices(choice=[
    app_commands.Choice(name="Bug", value="bug"),
    app_commands.Choice(name="Report", value="report")
    # ...
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, ask for an argument and add a type annotation.

```
@tree.command(name="createticket", description="Create a ticket", guild=discord.Object(GUILD_ID))
async def embed_command(interaction:discord.Interaction, report: str):
    ...
```

You can take this a step further with [app_commands.Range](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.app_commands.Range).

```
from discord import app_commands

@tree.command(name="createticket", description="Create a ticket", guild=discord.Object(GUILD_ID))
async def embed_command(interaction:discord.Interaction, report: app_commands.Range[str, 1, 10]:
```